# React navigation with Redux

Tags: react-native

I use Stack Navigator to pile up from A-B-C & I initialise my components in `componentDidMount()` function. When I press back on C it goes to B but nothing loads on screen. How can I restore my previous state from Redux store in my component as `componentDidMount()` or constructor is not called on going back.

This is how my home component loads a list

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.getHomeItems();
}
  
getHomeItems = () => {
 this.props.getHomeItems();
}

homeItems = () => {
  return Object.keys(this.props.homeItems).map( key => this.props.homeItems[key]);
}
```

and in the render function I render a list like this

```js
<List
  dataArray={this.homeItems()}
  renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} >
</List>
```

To go back from C to B on hw press event i use `dispatch(NavigationActions.back());`

Here is my home connect function

```js
function mapStateToProps(state){
 return {
  homeItems: state.home,
 }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(HomeActionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: Can you add some code on how you are trying to do that?

Comment: Which List component are you using ? ListView, FlatList ?

Comment: ListView of Nativebase from here http://docs.nativebase.io/COMPONENTS.html#List_Default

Comment: Is the list displayed in B before going to C.  Is homeItems props empty ?

Comment: @agent_hunt No it contains an array with length 1. I actually even put componentWillUpdate function & printed out this.props. When i go to C, array is present with length 1 but after C performs some action to redux store B's componentWillUpdate is called again & array length turns to 0. What i want is when i go back to B from C, how can i restore the state from redux store & regain access to list item.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Probably you haven't connected to redux properly.  How does your connect look like ?

Comment: @agent_hunt Check above i added more code

Comment: Got it to work thanks @agent_hunt. My problem was the new state being returned from the reducer, so i corrected that & everything works as expected.